# Why does my back end project in Node Js stops working in digital ocean?

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean, pm2

I have deployed a node project in digital ocean. Once in a while especially on weekends the api stops giving responses and gives me 504 error gateway timeout. When I check on the server what's going on with pm2 list it shows me that the status is online. I try the pm2 restart 0 or pm2 restart server.js and it starts working just fine until such thing happens again. 
I tried to use cron for this problem:

```
const CronJob = require("cron").CronJob;
const restartCommand = "pm2 restart 0";
const listCommand = "pm2 list";
const { exec } = require('child_process');

const restartApp = function () {
    exec(restartCommand, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (!err && !stderr) {
            console.log(new Date(), `App restarted!!!`);
            listApps();
        }
        else if (err || stderr) {
            console.log(new Date(), `Error in executing ${restartCommand}`, err || stderr);
        }
    });
}

function listApps() {
    exec(listCommand, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        // handle err if you like!
        console.log(`pm2 list`);
        console.log(`${stdout}`);
    });
}

new CronJob('0 0 17 * * *', function() {
    console.log('5 pm Los_Angeles time, restarting the gmd-server');
    restartApp();
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

Comment: Your title mentions a nodejs script problem, the code is a cron job. These are different things. Maybe your script has a memory problem.

Comment: this is a solution i found online actually but even before I added this script the same error occurred. What do you mean with memory problem? And how can I fix it? @RST